# What is the charset of URLs?

Tags: url, character-encoding

When someone types an url in a browser to access a page, which charset is used for that URL? Is there a standard? Can I consider that UTF-8 is used everywhere? Which characters are accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs may contain only a subset of ASCII, all URLs are valid ASCII.

[International domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) must be [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) encoded. Non-ASCII characters in the path or query parts must be encoded, with [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) being the generally agreed-upon standard.

Percent-encoding only takes the raw bytes and encodes each byte as `%xx`. There's no generally followed standard on what encoding should be used to determine a byte representation. As such, it's basically impossible to assume any particular character set being used in the percent-encoded representation. If you're creating those links, then you're in full control over the used charset before percent-encoding; if you're not, you're mostly out of luck. Though you will most likely encounter UTF-8, this is not guaranteed.